# How to calculate distinct 5-card hands in 7-card (Texas Hold'em) Poker using equivalence classes and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, poker

There are quite a few questions and answers here on specific holdings in poker and their frequency. I am more generally interested in the number of *distinct* 5-card hands that are possible in 7-card poker. That is, seven cards are drawn from a standard deck of 52, but only the best 5-card combo of all the possible combos in that 7-card draw counts.

For **example**: The draw is KKK87654, and contains also six cards of the same suit. That holding has 1) Three of a kind; 2) a straight; and 3) two flushes. But because the flush beats the other holdings, only the higher flush counts. So I don't want to count the lower flush, the trips, and the straight, as it would be double counting.

Another **example** is AT986**4**2. This is an Ace-high holding, with kickers T986. This hand is *equivalent* to AT986**3**2, because the lowest two cards are ignored in the evaluation.

By **equivalence classes** I mean:

1. Straight Flush (including Royal Flush)
2. Four of a Kind
3. Full House
4. Flush
5. Straight
6. Three of a Kind
7. Two Pair
8. One Pair
9. High Card

So, to summarize the question: how many distinct hands are there for each of these categories, and how to calculate them?

The exercise of counting all possible 5-card holdings in 5-card poker is relatively straight forward. There are ${52 \choose 5} \sim 2.6$ million holdings, but only [7642](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) distinct hands.

The problem gets trickier for 7 draws, because we need to discount "kickers" that may overturn the original hand, or because some holdings are not possible at all. For example, a 7-high holding is impossible a draw of 7 distinct cards will necessarily include at least one card higher than 7. I am stuck with the combinatorics of these cases.

Note that there are $52 \choose 7$ holdings possible ($\sim$ 133 million), but because of the restrictions referred to above, the number of distinct 5-card holding is supposed to reduce to just 4824.

Comment: This will be very arduous and error prone, because of all the special cases.  If the highest hand is a pair, we need to choose the other $5$ cards for $5$ different ranks other than that of the pair, so as not to make a straight or a flush.  The number possible ways to make a straight depend on which pair we hold.  The same problem arises for a two pair or trips.  If I really had to do this, I'd write a computer program.  There are many fewer cases than you think.  If we just consider how many cards of each rank we have, there are only $\binom{19}{12}=50,388$  cases ...

Comment: ... Once we've valued the hand, we can take suits into account, just as in the $5$-card case.

Comment: Actually there are fewer possibilities than I said.  I neglected to take into account that we can't have more than $4$ cards of any rank.  This reduces the total by $13\binom{14}1=182$ so there are $50,206$ possibilities.

Comment: Actually, it's not arduous, just complicated, especially from two Pair down. I can obviously write a program, but I would like to understand how the logic works in each case.

Comment: Yes, it's easier than I thought.  I was looking at it wrong. 
 Actually, I'm writing a detailed answer.  I would say it's not particularly complicated, but it is arduous. I suppose that's a matter of opinion, but  I've been working on it for several hours.  I hope to post an answer later today, if it turns out I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: I give up.  I haven't been able to make it balance.  [This Web page](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/comp20/) shows calculations.  I haven't reviewed them.

Comment: @saulspatz: I appreciate the effort!